# How to trim trailing $ when sed prints in "visually unambiguous" form?

Tags: shell, sed, escaping

I would like to list out escape characters literally.

Inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213510/150246):

```
printf '\033[m$123' | sed --quiet l
\033[m$123$                             # output: fail
```

But I would like to get rid of the tailing dollar sign.

It is possible to pipe the output into `sed` again:

```
printf '\033[m$123' | sed --quiet l | sed 's/\$$//'
\033[m$123                              # output: desired
```

Is it possible to group the two `sed` commands into one, reduce to one `sed` call only?

From the example 5.9.1 in the manual below, I tried to make use of the "hold space". But it seems do not work as expected.

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

```
printf '\033[m$123' | sed --quiet 'l ; H ; ${x;s/\$$//}'
\033[m$123$                             # output: fail
```

Comment: There is no tailing dollar in input. `l` command prints a `$` at the end of a line. If you run `printf '\033[m$123' | sed -n l | sed 's/\$$//' | sed -n l` you will see a trailing `$` again.

Comment: Thanks for spotting it. It seems having two pipes is already the simplest.

Comment: Does your version of `cat` support the `-t` option?

Comment: Thanks. `cat -t` is nice too. But the `^[` notation is not reusable by `printf '%b'`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
printf '\033[m$123' | sed 's/.*/echo '\''&'\'' | sed -n l0/e;s/.$//'
```

Invoke another sed invocation on every line using the `e` flag on the substitution command and then remove the last character.

N.B. The `l` commands output is determined the `-l` command line option or can be overridden by an integer value (here `0` which means no line length). This kind of command (others include `=, F, i, a, and c`) output directly to stdout and are immutable.

Comment: May I ask if the `e` command is the one mentioned in section 3.7 of https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands ? My `sed --version` is `sed (GNU sed) 4.9 ...`. The code output is `\033[m23` which is kind of weird. In addition, this solution invokes `sed` twice too. Any particular benefits? Thank you.

Comment: @midnite Yes it is the same, yes it does output that but it is not a sed irregularity but my mistake in not quoting the argument of the `echo` command, see edit. And thirdly, no benefit other than highlighting the ability to run other shell commands on the RHS of a substitute command (including `sed` itself).

Comment: I know `sed` but not really good at it. It is nice to see `sed` runs commands even in the RHS of the substitution. May I ask why `l/e;s/.$//` (output by `l` then trim last char) works inside, but `l;s/.$//` does not work outside? And it seems `l` and `l0` gives the same result.

Comment: @midnite as I said in the solution (last paragraph), the `l` command ouputs directly to the stdout and it is never in the pattern space (the place where sed operates on). However when the RHS of a substitution is evaluated it remains within the pattern space and thus can be substituted in subsequent  commands. Consider it as though the output of one sed invocation is piped directly into another.