# In shell script, how to shift positional parameters of the main script using a function?

Tags: shell, escaping, sh, positional-parameter, positional-argument

POSIX compliant shell script does not support arrays except the positional parameters array.

**Background:**

In the main script, several `case` conditions require running the same code with a different argument. Within the repeated code, it is necessary to to `shift` the positional parameters.

```
#!/bin/sh
# /tmp/test.sh

case "$1" in
( *one*   ) echo 1 ; shift ; echo 'more' ;;
( *two*   ) echo 2 ; shift ; echo 'more' ;;
( *three* ) echo 3 ; shift ; echo 'more' ;;
( other ) echo 'other' ;;
( * ) :
esac

printf '[%s]\n' "$@"
```

Test it:

```
$ /tmp/test.sh 'arg one'  '3   spaces' "with 'quotes'"
1
more
[3   spaces]
[with 'quotes']
```

To minimise code repetition (the actual code contains 10+ lines), how to wrap the similar `case` condition codes into a function?

**Trying to solve:**

```
#!/bin/sh
# /tmp/test.sh

newline=$(printf '\n ')
newline=${newline% }

func() {
    # Perform something based on arg $1.
    # But do not echo here. echo here will mess up with the return value.
    # Actual code do not echo here.
    # echo "$1"
    shift

    shift

    # Escape dangerous characters and preserve spaces
    modified_args=""
    for arg in "$@"; do
        trailing_newlines=${arg##*[!"${newline}"]}
        modified_args="${modified_args} '$(printf "%s" "$arg" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g")${trailing_newlines}'"
    done
    printf '%s' "$modified_args"
}

 case "$1" in
    ( *one*   ) args=$(func 1 "$@") ; eval set -- "$args" ;;
    ( *two*   ) args=$(func 2 "$@") ; eval set -- "$args" ;;
    ( *three* ) args=$(func 3 "$@") ; eval set -- "$args" ;;
    ( other ) echo 'other' ;;
    ( * ) :
    esac


printf '[%s]\n' "$@"
```

Test output:

```
$ newline=$(printf '\n ')
$ newline=${newline% }
$ /tmp/test.sh 'arg one'  '3   spaces' '' "with 'quotes'" 'double "quote"' "$newline line two $newline line three $newline$newline"
[3   spaces]
[]
[with 'quotes']
[double "quote"]
[
 line two 
 line three 

]
```

- With a heads-up from @KamilCuk, I have made modifications to fix the issue of trailing newlines being trimmed.

It seems okay. But the concern is, if `'$(printf "%s" "$arg" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g")'` escaping only the single quote **safe enough**?

I try to look into how `getopt` does the escape.

https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/9abd5e4b99fb2d78d8dbbb9144aef68972c65e83/misc-utils/getopt.c#L133-L172

It seems that `getopt` only escape the single quote also, except when `--shell tcsh`.

Comment: Note that `'$(printf "%s" "$arg" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g")'` removes trailing newlines.

Comment: This will be fragile no matter what, but you might look at the `%q` specifier of printf.

Comment: Thank you KamilCuk for spotting this bug. It is because this call of subshell `$( ... )` trims the trailing newline. I am considering solutions to avoid it. (1) If tailing newline is the only concern, I may save the number of tailing newline beforehand, then add it back afterwards. (2) If other non-print characters are also concerns, I may escape them by `sed -n 'l' ...`, then use `printf '%b'` afterwards. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77628265/1884546

Comment: WilliamPursell, Thanks. `printf %q` is not POSIX.

Comment: Related/Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/13354247/589924

Comment: Related and a good SO thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash

Answer (score 0):

There is no sane way to manipulate the global value of `$@` from inside a function. My suggestion would be to refactor your code to avoid the repetitions by other means.

Perhaps like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

what=""
case "$1" in
  ( *one*   ) echo 1; what='more' ;;
  ( *two*   ) echo 2; what='yet more' ;;
  ( *three* ) echo 3; what='still more' ;;
  ( other ) what='other' ;;
  ( * ) ;;
esac
shift
[ "$what" ] && echo "$what"

printf '[%s]\n' "$@"
```

Comment: If my suggestion follows the same approach as `getopt`, I believe it is no more dangerous. I also hope for a good refactor. The `case` statement is used to process position parameters parsed by `getopt`. Out of the 20 options, around 10 may have an additional optional argument. For these 10 options, there are checks, and each has an inner `case` construct to handle the argument. A possible refactor is grouping these 10 options into one `case`, using an inner `case` to determine which parameter to use. However, this will reduce readability.

Comment: I was imagining something like that, but your (too) minimal example does not have a `while` loop at all. Maybe (accept this, or post an answer of your own and accept that, and) ask a new question with all your requirements spelled out.

Comment: I have just updated the code with more detailed information. I am wondering if there is a better way to refactor it.

Comment: Changing the questions so that answers no longer make sense is not acceptable. Again, ask a new question with your actual requirements (and maybe delete this question, or accept this answer).

Comment: As said, Question not changed: How to shift positional parameters of the main script using a function?

Comment: But the code you updated was substantially changed, to the point where this answer looked like it belonged on a different question.

Comment: It depends if you (or other readers) prefer an abstract example code addressing the question, or a more detailed code reflecting the actual scenario. Both the previous shorter code and the later longer code is asking the same question: to or not to perform `shift` inside a function to reduce code repetition.

Comment: @midnite: by longstanding convention here, we generally roll back a major question edit if it would invalidate an existing answer. To fix this situation: you can grab your new edit (from the revision history), ask it as a new question, and link back to this question for context. Answerers (including tripleee) can answer that new one if they wish.